# Jest snapshots work locally but consistently fail on Travis CI

Tags: reactjs, travis-ci, jestjs, enzyme, babel-jest

My Jest snapshot tests consistently fail on Travis with the following difference:

```
-      "_instance": Constructor {
+      "_instance":  {
```

Dev dependencies include:

```
"babel-jest": "^19.0.0",
"jest": "^19.0.2",
"react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
"react-test-renderer": "^15.4.2",
"enzyme": "^2.7.1",
"enzyme-to-json": "^1.5.0",
"react": "^15.2.0",
"react-dom": "^15.2.1"
```

Using Node 7.0.0 locally and on Travis.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you run it with the same command. We had this problem when we run it with code coverage on CI system.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Yup! We're using `npm run jest`.

Comment: @JaredSilver can you please comment on the approved answer? What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would make sure that I am using the exact same version on both locally and on CI. Try pinning `jest` and `babel-jest` to a specific version:

```
"babel-jest": "=19.0.0",
"jest": "=19.0.2",
```

Maybe I would do the same with **all the dependencies**! Then remove `node_modules/` from your machine, run the tests (update snapshots if necessary) and push.

Ps. I would also try to empty the caches on travis: `https://travis-ci.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY_NAME/caches`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had a mismatch between the node version in the build system vs local.